# How can I programatically control multi-display setup?

Tags: c#, windows, screen, multiple-monitors, win64

I use a laptop +a widescreen monitor, as dual screen setup. Half the time when I reconnect the laptop back after working on it standalone , the dual-screen settings gets automatically switched to "single screen" and I have to go and switch it back.

How can I do that programatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is a keyboard shortcut
  [Windows key] + [P]

Comment: this answer should probably be in SuperUser but the question clearly shouldn't